# Android : Value is not storing in table

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application I have task Fragment. I have 3 fields such as employee name, project name and task. I'am fetching all the employee name and project name and am showing it in spinner. So after selecting that employee name and project name, I'am getting the employee id and project id and am storing those values in a task table.

Create button code.

```
tsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = tname.getText().toString();
            task.setName(name);
            task.setEid(selectedManager);
            task.setPid(selectedProject);
            db.addTask(task);
            tname.setText(" ");

            Toast.makeText(ctx, "value added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

addTask method in the DataBaseHandler class

```
    public void addTask(Task task) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TASKNAME, task.getName()); 
        values.put(KEY_TASKEID, task.getEid()); 
        values.put(KEY_TASKPID, task.getPid());
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_TASKS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Here value of employee id is storing for both fields employee id and project id. But when I debug the app, I can get the employee id and project id in the ContentValues. But I don't know why the value of project id is not storing in the table.

In the following line I can see the correct project id value

```
values.put(KEY_TASKPID, task.getPid());
db.insert(TABLE_TASKS, null, values);
```

Please do help me. Thanks in advance.

DatabaseHandler code

```
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TaskManager";
//  table name
private static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEES = "Employee";
private static final String TABLE_PROJECTS = "project";
private static final String TABLE_TASKS = "Task";
// employee Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_DESIG = "designation";

//Project Table

private static final String KEY_ID1 = "id1";
private static final String KEY_NAME1 = "name1";
private static final String KEY_EID1 = "eid";
private static final String KEY_DESIG1 = "designation1";

// Task table

private static final String KEY_TASKID = "idtask";
private static final String KEY_TASKNAME = "taskname";
private static final String KEY_TASKEID = "taskeid";
private static final String KEY_TASKPID = "taskpid";
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_EMPLOYEES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EMPLOYEES + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DESIG + " TEXT" + ")";
    String CREATE_PROJECTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PROJECTS + "("
            + KEY_ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME1 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EID1 + " TEXT," + KEY_DESIG1 + " TEXT" + ")";
    String CREATE_TASKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASKS + "("
            + KEY_TASKID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TASKNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TASKEID + " TEXT," + KEY_TASKPID + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEES_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PROJECTS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TASKS_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: Check your db contract class.. What does `KEY_TASKPID` resolve to? Maybe you copy/pasted a different value? What is the DDL of `TABLE_TASKS`? Maybe Project Id is accidentally an `AUTOINCREMENT`?

Comment: @323go I hope everything is correct.Project id is not auto incrementing. Employee id is storing for the project id also. Please check my question. updated.

Comment: are you getting any error while inserting?